# Understanding the interaction between difference, beveling (and maybe shrinkwrap)

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to learn how to use boolean operations and modifiers as part of an attempt to build a functional-ly oriented library for Blender (which is why most of what I an describing happens in python scripts)

Specifically, I tried to subtract a cube from another cube like this:

[image]

and then bevel the edges of the result like this:

[image]

However I want also the edges formed by the difference operation to be beveled - but that does not seem to happen. Also, when I dump the number of edges of the difference the count is 12.

By googling around I ended up thinking that the problem could be handled by first shrink-wrapping, and *then* beveling.

However the result shown here (different angle than the pictures before - for clarity) is decidedly not what I was looking for.

[image]

I guess I am either missing an intermediate step or getting some parameters wrong.

What is it?

Comment: is it what you want? https://zupimages.net/up/21/29/mkwj.jpg You can get bevel in the inner angles if that's what you're looking for. Also I'm not sure about your Shrinkwrap thing. Maybe try to reformulate your question to make it clearer?

Comment: @moonboots - yes that is what I was looking for for now. The shrinkwrap thing is probably a different question then - like "how can I turn a boolean into a single mesh?"

Comment: Bevel the boolean object before you apply it.

Comment: @moonboots - it all happens in a script - I'll have to extract that into something sensible, later today. Thanks in the meantime. Re shrinkwrap: what O wanted is this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202297/convert-boolean-objects-to-a-single-mesh